# Is amyl nitrite used for sex?

Tags: sex, recreational-drugs

Do people use it for sex somehow? What is the effect? Just in the book,"Fight Club", the author describes this drug in a sex related context.

Comment: I edited your question to change amyl nitrate to amyl nitrite, which I think is what you meant. They're very different compounds so if you really did mean amyl nitrate, you can revert my edits.

Answer (score 5):

[Amyl Nitrite](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMHT0008992/?report=details)

> Treats and prevents chest pain (angina pectoris).

And more pertinent for the question:

> On the street, this medicine and others like it are sometimes called
>   "poppers." They have been used by some people to cause a "high" or to
>   improve sex. Use in this way is not recommended. Amyl nitrite can
>   cause serious harmful effects if too much is inhaled.

Poppers are a name for inhaled nitrites which Amyl Nitrite is one of the most common. They can be lethal if used [recreationally](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14740789) and cause vasodilation.

> Poppers are rapid-onset, short-acting potent vasodilators that produce
>   a rush characterized by warm sensations and feelings of dizziness.
>   Poppers sometimes are used to facilitate anal intercourse because of
>   their actions on the anal sphincter.

I have read reports about them being similar to Viagra and having a psychedelic effect. I have also included the [Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppers).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, I am just somehow confused, because the OP is asking about "Amyl nitrAte" and not "Amyl nitrIte", which are different substances in my knowledge. Probably this a typing error, but it would be nice if the OP (@Chank) could just clarify this. BR. MA

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith I'm sure the OP meant amyl nitrite, so I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @CareyGregory. Ok. Thanks for the feedback. BR. MA